# TypeScript declaration for polymorphic decorator

Tags: typescript, polymorphism, decorator

I’m in the process of writing an ambient declaration for [react-tracking](https://github.com/NYTimes/react-tracking). It exposes a `track` decorator that can be used on both classes *and* methods.

A simplified example taken from the docs:

```
import track from 'react-tracking'

@track({ page: 'FooPage' })
export default class FooPage extends React.Component {

  @track({ action: 'click' })
  handleClick = () => {
    // ...
  }
}
```

In my ambient declaration file I expected to be able to do something like the following and have TypeScript choose the right overload:

```
declare function track(trackingInfo?: any, options?: any): <T>(component: T) => T
declare function track(trackingInfo?: any, options?: any): any

export default track
```

While this works well for component classes, it fails for methods with the following error:

```
[ts] Unable to resolve signature of method decorator when called as an expression.
```

Looking at the typing that TS chooses for this application of the decorator indicates it’s not falling back to the signature that should match anything, but instead to the component class one.

[image]

Is it possible to type a polymorphic decorator at all? And, if so, what am I doing wrong?

---

UPDATE: Here’s a reduced simplified example.

The first one is monomorphic and works as expected:

```
function trackClass(trackingInfo?: any, options?: any): ClassDecorator {
  return null
}

function trackMethod(trackingInfo?: any, options?: any): MethodDecorator {
  return null
}

@trackClass({})
class Foo {
  @trackMethod({})
  someMethod() {}
}
```

This second example is polymorphic and fails for both:

```
function track(trackingInfo?: any, options?: any): ClassDecorator | MethodDecorator {
  return null
}

@track({})
class Bar {
  @track({})
  someMethod() {}
}
```

Comment: The second example won't work because you have a function that is a `ClassDecorator | MethodDecorator` - you want to say that the return type is a `ClassDecorator & MethodDecorator` since it will "do the right thing" when the decorator is invoked.

Answer (score 3):

TypeScript's `lib.d.ts` has a `ClassDecorator` and a `MethodDecorator` type:

```
declare type ClassDecorator = <TFunction extends Function>(target: TFunction) => TFunction | void;

declare type MethodDecorator = <T>(target: Object, propertyKey: string | symbol, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<T>) => TypedPropertyDescriptor<T> | void;
```

You can either do one of two things:

1. Create a type that has overloads that are compatible with both:

   ```
   interface TrackDecorator {
       // Class decorator overload
       <TFunction extends Function>(target: TFunction): TFunction;

       // Property decorator overload
       <T>(target: Object, propertyKey: string | symbol, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<T>): TypedPropertyDescriptor<T>;
   }

   export default function track(trackingData?: object): TrackDecorator;
   ```
2. Derive a type to combine the overloads appropriately.

   ```
   interface TrackDecorator extends ClassDecorator, MethodDecorator { }
   export default function track(trackingData?: object): TrackDecorator;
   ```

The former allows you to be more specific, but the latter will tie you to whatever version TypeScript has in mind for decorators (in other words, if the spec changes, it will be implied that `react-tracking` supports either version).

Comment: Thanks thus far, Daniel! I get what you’re saying, but still can’t figure out a way to actually make it work. The `track` function returns either a class decorator function or a method decorator function, I’ve updated my post with a reduced example that shows just the problem of returning either one of those types.

Comment: I found the issue. When I used `dts-gen` to create the new DefinitelyTyped package it had set `lib: "es6"` in `tsconfig.json`, whereas I apparently needed `target: "es6"`. Now your suggestions started to work as expected. If that makes sense, can you update your answer to include that so I can accept the answer?